# Picasso displays image smaller than expected (half expected size)

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso to load images from URLs like this one and display them in my Android app: http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/A7HtCxFe7Ms8H7e7o2zawppbuDT.jpg

However, the problem is that they are displaying half their original size.  I can't figure out why.

Loading the URL above directly in a browser, you get an image 185px x 278px

I saved one of the images locally to use as a dummy image for debugging. When I use `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dummyimage);` the image appears as the correct size. (Sorry, I tried to attach a screenshot, but I don't have high enough Reputation.)

However, when I use `Picasso.with(mContext).load(mMoviePosterURL).into(imageView);` to load the images, they appear half that size.  (I would attach a screenshot if I could.)

Here's my ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_imageview"
    android:src="@drawable/dummyimage">
</ImageView>
```

And my layout:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit">
</GridView>
```

The full code of my getView method in the BaseAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

           //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dummyimage);  for comparison

            if(mMoviePosterPaths!=null) {
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                   .load(mMoviePosterPaths[position])
                   .into(imageView);
            }
            return imageView;
        }
```

I have found a couple workarounds.  One is by doing this: `.resize(185*2,278*2)`, but I would want to avoid upscaling the image if possible.

Another is to call a larger image from the API that's providing the images, however I feel this is less efficient since it requires more data.

Searching around I haven't found anyone else with this issue so maybe I'm just doing something dumb, but I'm stumped :(

I guess the main thing here is that I'm trying to understand why `imageView.setImageResource()` and `Picasso {...}` display the same image differently.

Thank you

Comment: It's quite unclear what do you mean by saying `displaying half their original size`. Does it looks smaller? And what is size of `@drawable/dummyimage`?

Comment: Just to make sure : You do know that with Android we don't deal with pixels but with dp (density-independent pixel) instead?

Comment: @Foxinsocks I would attach a screenshot but I don't have enough Reputation.  Basically, when I use setImageResource() on a local copy of the file, it appears as expected.  When I use Picasso it appears smaller than expected (half of expected size)

Comment: @Foxinsocks I have some screenshots on this thread where I also asked this question.  Thanks https://discussions.udacity.com/t/images-loaded-by-picasso-are-smaller-than-original-size-and-do-not-fill-the-imageview/27902

Comment: @Foxinsocks Size of `@drawable/dummyimage` is 185x278

Comment: @poss Thanks. I would suspect this is the problem, however I'm not specifying any dimensions, I would just like the image to display at it's original size.  `.setImageResource()` on a local copy of the image displays twice as large as using `Picasso`.  For now I'm using `Picasso....resize(185*2, 278*2)` as a workaround until I find a better solution.  Thanks

Comment: Screen density does matter however. To give you example 278px image **at xhdpi** will be 22.07mm (or 0.87in). The same 278px image **at xxxhdpi** will be 11.03mm (or 0.43in). It's exactly half the size as you may have noticed - that's where your difference might be coming from. I'd recommend running emulator with different settings and screen densities to see if this is the reason for your issue.

Comment: I have the same problem, it is as if picasso is scaling the image without telling you. Did you ever find a solution ? Works fine if I use the image from R, but not if I download and set it using picasso.

Answer (score 1):

You resize the image to double of its original size. That's why the image show only half. Try removing

```
.resize(185*2,278*2)
```

or adjust the width and height.

```
.resize(185,278)
```

And in your ImageView, add

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you.  To clarify, `.resize(185*2,278*2)` is the workaround.  When I remove it, or when I use `.resize(185,278)`, it appears half size (smaller than expected).  I have tried `scaleType="fitXY"` and it didn't work, but I will try again. Thanks

Comment: I once used Picasso and I had some problems. I am using UIL now. Test with UIL, too :)

Comment: Add .fit().centerInside() in your existing Picasso codes and try again.

Comment: Tried your suggestions.  `scaleType="fitXY"` and `.fit().centerInside()`.  Didn't work.  Thanks though.  I could do some workarounds like multiplying the dimensions *2 (which just seems weird), or I could call a larger image from the API (however this seems less efficient, since it would use more data)

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, but using `android:scaleType="fitXY"` attribute in `AppCompatImageView` I got the exact same size as original size.

XML:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/student_photo_preview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/student"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

JAVA code:

```
getPicassoUnsafeCertificate(context).load(student.getPhoto())
                            .fit()
                            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image)
                            .error(R.drawable.no_image)
                            .into(previewImage);
```

I used `getPicassoUnsafeCertificate()` custom method for turning off the SSL verification check (I'm not concerned with this part but I added for additional benefit).